# emberJS to dynamically load a model upon clicking on a component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm trying to load a page with a list of several persons, and an "address" link next to each, person and address are separate models in my rails backend, I want ember to load the list of persons when showing the list, and requesting from the backend the single addresses as the user clicks on the link.

I understand that the components should not be calling the store directly, but I'm struggling to understand how the controller could do that.

here's my current (non working) code:

```
// app/router.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
});

export default Router;
```

---

```
// app/routes/about.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('person');
  }
});
```

---

```
// app/models/person.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  first_name: DS.attr('string'),
  last_name: DS.attr('string'),
  birthday: DS.attr('date'),
  address: DS.belongsTo('address')
});
```

---

```
// app/models/address.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstLine: DS.attr('string'),
  postCode: DS.attr('string'),
  town: DS.attr('string'),
  person: DS.belongsTo('person')
});
```

---

```
// app/controllers/about.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    toggleAddress(user) {
      if(this.get('shown_address') == null) {
          this.set("address", this.store.query('address', user));
          this.set('shown_address', user);
      } else {
        this.set("shown_address", null)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

---

```
// app/components/about-address.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
});
```

---

```
<!-- app/templates/components/about-address.hbs -->

{{#if shown_address}}
  {{shown_address.first_name}} {{shown_address.last_name}}<br/>
  address: {{address}} <br/>
  <a href="" {{action "toggleAddress" user}}>Address</a>
{{else}}
  hidden:
  <a href="" {{action "toggleAddress" user}}>Address</a>
{{/if}}
```

---

```
<!-- app/templates/about.hbs -->
<h1>about</h1>

  {{#each model as |user|}}
    <h3>Welcome '{{user.first_name}}'</h3>
    {{about-address user=user}}
  {{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

---

Any clues about how to solve this?

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? It looks like you are calling an action in your component template that doesn't exist in your component. You will need to sendAction from this component action up to your controller.